# Where will the address of pointers be stored in memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, virtual-memory

I'm studying virtual memory and free space management.

I know the pointers which we allocate using malloc will request a chunk of memory in heap.
But when we call a malloc () system call, it will return an integer as address of dedicated chunk of memory, but where will this address be stored itself?

Assume

```
int *ptr = malloc (16);
```

returns 4008 address of mem. and it starts from 4008 to 4022. this chunk is in heap. but where is 4008 itself?

Is it stored in stack?

Comment: it's an rvalue so it isn't stored in any defined memory location based on that. In your case, since you do `int *ptr = ...`, you are storing that rvalue on the stack. If you would just do `malloc (16);` without the `int *ptr =`, the value would be discarded after `malloc` returned it and not stored anywhere.

Comment: I think you fundamentally are confused, memory is linear, addresses start from 0 and go up to N depending on how much memory is available, an address itself isn't quite that simple as on some platforms like Intel there is a segment and offset to represent an address, this isn't quite as straight forward....on flat memory architectures, the memory addressing is as I first stated, 0 to N.  But an address is not stored anywhere, its just a reference to a location which when you try to read a location you supply.

Comment: It's stored in the same place as the number 42.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering your example code:

```
int *ptr = malloc(16);
```

The pointer `ptr` is initialized to the return value of `malloc`. Let's assume `malloc` returns `4008`. Thus, the *value* of `ptr` becomes `4008`. Depending on the compiler, this value may end up being stored only in a register, in which case technically `ptr` has no address, but since the compiler needs to behave as though it did, if you take the address of `ptr` (such as by the expression `&ptr`, having type `int **`) the pointer will be stored on the stack with other local variables. Meanwhile, the value(s) pointed to by `ptr` will be stored at the address returned by `malloc`, in this example `4008`.

Comment: Note that apart from the use as a pointer, this is not fundamentally different from `int i = 4008;`

Comment: You mean the variable ptr which has the value of 4008 itself will be stored same way as int i = 4008; ?

Comment: @RamtinMousavi In practice (on all platforms that I'm familiar with) pointers _are_ integers and generally stored in exactly the same way as an integer variable of the same width would be. The value stored just happens to be a memory address.

Answer (score 1):

In C, there are fundamentally three types of memory for data (omitting constant ones):

- normal, global "data"
- stack, used for local data
- heap, dynamic managed data

The first area has a fixed size, determined at compilation time; everything in it is a variable, with an address and a size. The second area, the stack, is similar to the first: everything stored in it has a name, i.e. it is a variable. The difference from local data and global data is that local data exist only when executing a function, and then disappear. In other words, every function has its local, temporary data, which can be thought exactly like the global data, but will disappear.

There are two notes to be added. First, I wrote "stack" because often is a stack, but this is not mandatory; what is important is that is *temporary*. Second note is: everything the program does or manages, must start from a **variable**, which resides in global or local data. Those variables are the gate to all the other memory.

The most interesting area is the third, the heap. At the program start, probably there is no heap (or it is empty). To use the heap, the program must allocate ("ask") memory from it. The requested memory is now "reserved" to the program, which must store an address (or, a "handle") to that area. Without storing the address, the program is not able to access that memory.

The heap is also special because it is the only area which is totally managed by the programmer, not by the compiler.

Everything always comes from *variables*. So the question "where will the address of pointers be stored" can be only one: in a variable. Unless it was stored in the heap itself, in an area accessible via a pointer, which is stored again into a variable in local or global data.